# Restricting access on directories under repositories

Tags: artifactory

Is there a way to set permissions to the directory level under the repository?

We have about 200 project teams in our environment, so we would like to have only 3 common repositories DEV, TEST, PROD for all the teams to contribute.

While under DEV we would have a directory created for each project to upload or to deploy code from CI.

I would like to restrict the creation of directories under DEV by normal users and by the CI systems, however, they should be able to create directories below their project directories.

**Example:**

```
DEV   
  |_ PROJECT   
            |_ _ BUILD 1   
            |_ _ BUILD 2
```

Here DEV is a REPO and PROJECT is the Project Teams directory and BUILD1 and BUILD2 are the builds of the Project.

I would like to restrict users to create any directory under DEV but they should be able to create directories under the PROJECT.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there is. You need to use inclusion and exclusion patterns in [the Permission Target](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Permissions).

Inclusion pattern `DEV/PROJECT/BUILD1/**/*.*` works as a whitelist, limiting the user or group to `BUILD1` only.